# How to get the last row with null value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table:

```
a       b       c
1       11      21
2       12      22
3       3       3
NaN     14      24
NaN     15      NaN 
4       4       4
5       15      25
6       6       6
7       17      27
```

I want to remove all the rows in column `a` before the last row with the null value. The output that I want is:

```
a       b       c
NaN     15      NaN 
4       4       4
5       15      25
6       6       6
7       17      27
```

I couldn't find a better solution for this but `first_valid_index` and `last_valid_index`. I think I don't need that.

---

**BONUS**

I also want to add a new column in the dataframe if all the values in a row are the same. The following rows should have the same value:

```
new       a       b       c
NaN       NaN     15      NaN 
4         4       4       4
4         5       15      25
6         6       6       6
6         7       17      27
```

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Is your "table" a DataFrame or something else? (2) There is no `null` in Python. Is it a `None` or a `nan` or something else?

Comment: I edited the question with NaN in place of null.

Comment: If you find at least one row with the same values you add one more column? And what values will the column have?

Comment: If I find the same value, the new column will also store the same value. And the rows that will also store that values from the previous column until another row is found with the same value in all the columns

Answer (score 0):

Find the rows that contain an `NaN`:

```
nanrows = df['a'].isnull()
```

Find the index of the last of them:

```
nanmax = df[nanrows].index.max()
```

Do slicing:

```
df.iloc[nanmax:]
#     a   b     c
#4  NaN  15   NaN
#5  4.0   4   4.0
#6  5.0  15  25.0
#7  6.0   6   6.0
#8  7.0  17  27.0
```

Comment: Do I have to mention the column name when I find the rows that contain any NaNs? Because I want to find NaNs in the column a only

Comment: I overlooked that part. Yes, you have to. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isna` with `idxmax`:

```
new_df = df.iloc[df["a"].isna().idxmax()+1:]
```

Output:

```
     a   b     c
4  NaN  15   NaN
5  4.0   4   4.0
6  5.0  15  25.0
7  6.0   6   6.0
8  7.0  17  27.0
```

Then use `pandas.Series.where` with `nunique`:

```
new_df["new"] = new_df["a"].where(new_df.nunique(axis=1).eq(1)).ffill()
print(new_df)
```

Final output:

```
     a   b     c  new
4  NaN  15   NaN  NaN
5  4.0   4   4.0  4.0
6  5.0  15  25.0  4.0
7  6.0   6   6.0  6.0
8  7.0  17  27.0  6.0
```